# Connecting an Access Database to Excel using an OLEDB Connection

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am wondering if anyone can help me? I have no real clue on how to do what I am attempting and I am just guessing based off the bits of information I have.

We use Microsoft Access to pull information out of our Trading program, we set this up via a DSN using an ODBC Connection.

We then pull the information out of Access into Excel. We have always gotten data from the Access databases as a Connection rather than a query if that makes sense? This way we can keep amending the Connection String and The command text to suit where as if you get the data via a query the options are greyed out in the connection properties in excel (I hope that sentence makes sense)

I need to add a second connection to an excel workbook, to get queries from two different databases, however I am struggling to create a connection from scratch, where for the last 12 years we have just been amending an existing connection and saving the spreadsheet under a new name no one here knows how to create a new connection.

I have tried the following > Get Data > From Database > From Microsoft Access Database

This imports but I am unable to change the SQL command text so its no good.

I am trying to add a connection via OLEDB using the following Connection String

***Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database\Dormant Accounts.mdb;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};***

But I am getting the error Details: "OLE DB: Could not find installable ISAM."

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 is installed, I have been googling all morning trying to find answers to this question but I am having no joy, Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this to work?

If it helps, the connection string we always copy and amend from is the following

***DBQ=C:\Database\Revenue Report.mdb;DefaultDir=C:\Database;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;MaxScanRows=8;PageTimeout=5;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;***

The only changing variable would be the file name, this works but I have no idea what the provider is or if this was even set up as an OLEDB connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if you would need any more info

Comment: If you are not using **Get Data > From Database** option, I'm presuming that you want to do this via VBA.. is that correct?

Comment: Hi Zac, thanks for responding, problem is I dont know! I honestly have no idea how these connections have been set up, all I can see is an existing connection in Excel and I dont know how to replicate it. This is is a screenshot of what I am looking at but I dont know how the original creator got here https://imgur.com/a/8Gf3iMd

Comment: I can't see the screenshot. Might be worth adding it to your post. Either way, I don't think you need Microsoft Access. You could import information straight from DSN into Excel (either via connection through Excel or via VBA)